# How to drag and drop an Excel row to a textbox in a web page in HTML or c#

Tags: c#, html, excel

I know how to make any HTML element into a drag and drop area and how to use the `ondrag()` and `ondrop()` features. But now I want to be able to drag and drop a row from an Excel sheet to the HTML element (textbox).

My question is: how do I achieve this? Is it possible?

I've been trying to drag and drop from Excel to like a text file but it doesn't work. Do I have to enable drag and drop in Excel or is it just not possible to drag items out of Excel?

Comment: It's possible, when you drag and drop a row it's just text and the columns are separated by a tab.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site